# Tensorflow: How to convert scalar tensor to scalar variable in python?

Tags: tensorflow

In Tensorflow, I'd like to convert a scalar tensor to an integer. Is it possible to do?

I need to create a loop and the index of the loop is a scalar tensor, and inside the loop body, I want to use the index to access an entry in a tensor array.

For example:

```
idx = tf.constant(0)
c = lambda i : tf.less(i, 10)
def body(idx) :
  i = # convert idx to int 
  b = weights[i]  # access an entry in a tensor array, tensor cannot be used directly
  ....
  return idx+1
tf.while_loop(c, body, [idx])
```

Answer (score -7, accepted):

You need to evaluate a tensor to get a value.

If you want to do this:

```
i = # convert idx to int
```

you can do sess.run() or idx.eval():

```
i = sess.run(idx)
```

Comment: I need to do it during graph construction, not in a session. The while loop would construct the graph. Is that possible?

Comment: @Fei it's not possible without sess.run()/eva(). Then, you may want to use numpy array.

Answer (score 20):

In Tensorflow 2.0+, it's as simple as:

```py
my_tensor.numpy()
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'

Comment: @iirekm: Perhaps you don't have eager execution enabled? You can see the method is defined here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/88e357042ea79e0c8a4b906f76494ab306754c7d/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py#L1042-L1067

Comment: What can we do if eager execution is not enabled?

Comment: If eager execution is not enabled, you wouldn't convert `idx` to a scalar `i` and you wouldn't index `weights` as `weights[i]`. Instead, you would use `tf.gather(weights, idx)`.

Answer (score 11):

It should be as simple as calling `int()` on your tensor.

```py
int(tf.random.uniform((), minval=0, maxval=32, dtype=tf.dtypes.int32))
>> 4
```

I've checked this in TF 2.2 and 2.4

Comment: Though you should probably have a look at `gather` if you are trying to do things with tensors and indexes.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a tf.Session() in order to cast a tensor to scalar

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    scalar = tensor_scalar.eval()
```

If you are using IPython Notebooks, you can use `Interactive Session`:

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
scalar = tensor_scalar.eval()
# Other ops
sess.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

**2.0 Compatible Answer**: Below code will convert a Tensor to a Scalar.

```
!pip install tensorflow==2.0
import tensorflow as tf
tf.__version__ #'2.0.0'
x = tf.constant([[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]])
Reduce_Sum_Tensor = tf.reduce_sum(x)
print(Reduce_Sum_Tensor) #<tf.Tensor: id=11, shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=6>
print(Reduce_Sum_Tensor.numpy()) # 6, which is a Scalar
```

[This](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/gist/rmothukuru/932a0e16efbf3f98c3cf3ca9b68c93cf/so_37049411.ipynb) is the Link of the Google Colab, in which the above code is executed.

Comment: AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'

Comment: In tensorflow version 2.2.0 or even 2.3.0 , AttributeError as above exists. It works only in 2.0.0. Could anyone help on how to convert to numpy array in versions >= 2.2

Answer (score -2):

Try to use tf.reshape()

```
# tensor 't' is [7]
# shape `[]` reshapes to a scalar
reshape(t, []) ==> 7
```

This comes from the https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reshape

Comment: The documentation is wrong, it doesn't actually convert a 0D tensor to a python scalar.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe this help. Just simple use:

```py
idx2np = int(idx)
```

You could test whether it is a number now:

```py
test_sum = idx2np + 1
print(str(test_sum))
```